# Proof of a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a given series such that it satisfies the following conditions for all sequence  $\{y_n\}$ in real numbers converging to $0$. It is given that the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to $0$ and the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_ny_n$ is convergent. Then show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_n|$ is convergent$,$ that is the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ is absolutely convergent.

My attempt: Since $\{y_n\}$ is converges to $0$ then for each $ε>0$ there exist a natural number $k_1$ such that $|y_n|< ε$ for all $n>k_1$. Since the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_ny_n$ is convergent then the tail of the series goes to zero that is $x_ny_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. But can not proceed further to complete the proof. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not following.  Suppose $y_n=0$ for all $n$. $x_n=1$ Then $y_n\to 0$ and $\sum x_ny_n$ converges, but $\sum |x_n|$ does not.

Comment: Can you clarify or edit your question?  It's simply wrong as stated.  Perhaps you gave the wrong assumptions?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is wrong as stated.  If you can, please edit.

Comment: Sorry at first I can't understand the question. Now I have edited it. @lulu thank you for concern about it

Comment: Oh, so this is meant to hold for all sequences $\{y_n\}$ which go to $0$?  Fair enough.  I'll withdraw the close vote.

Comment: I don't understand your line of attack, though.  I think the idea has to be:  assume $\sum |x_n|$ diverges and construct a sequence $\{y_n\}$ which goes to $0$  for which $\sum x_ny_n$ diverges.

Comment: @lulu. The main idea is for a given sequence $\{x_n\}$, and for all those sequences say $\{y_n\}$ those are converges to $0$, $\{x_n\}$ satisfies $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_ny_n<\infty$ that is converges. Then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ is absolutely convergent. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sum |x_n|=\infty$.  We will construct a sequence $\{y_n\}$ such that $y_n\to 0$ and $\sum x_ny_n$ diverges.

Since $\sum |x_n|=\infty$  we can find a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $N_i$ such that the partial sums satisfy $$\sum_{n=1}^{N_k}|x_n|>k$$

Now define $y_n$ by $$N_k≤n<N_{k+1}\implies y_n=\text {sign} (x_n)\times \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}$$

Clearly $y_n\to 0$.  We remark that the partial sum 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N_k}x_ny_n≥ \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}\sum_{n=1}^{N_k} |x_n|≥\sqrt {
k}$$

Hence the partial sums for $\{x_ny_n\}$ tend to $\infty$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you sir. Great one.

Answer (score 3):

Look at $x_n=y_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_ny_n$ converges, but $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_n|=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ is divergent !

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I have edited my question sir.